# What are the units of the values returned from sp_whoisactive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the nice [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) made by Adam Machanic.

The documentation is however a little sparse. Specifically the meaning and units of the columns provided is unclear to me.

How should I understand "number of physical reads"? Can I convert this to e.g. MB or is it not a 1to1 conversion? Are tempdb_allocations and reads given in those same units?

For CPU: "For an active request, total CPU time consumed by the current query"

Does this mean cpu time in seconds, milliseconds? Does it count double when parallelized?

I am running this command:

```
sp_whoisactive @filter_type='login', @filter='myusername', @get_plans=1
```

and this one for the help text:

```
sp_whoisactive  @help=1
```

Comment: Side note: sp_whoisactive is not nice, it's great! :) But it's made by Adam Machanic. Only the "table-log"-part is made by Brent.

Comment: Straight from documentation - http://whoisactive.com/docs/07_default/ .. its 8KB pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SQL Server, reads are generally measured in 8KB pages. (There are some exceptions with in-memory OLTP, for example.) TempDB is measured in those same units.

CPU time is measured in milliseconds, and is the total of CPU time consumed across all logical cores, so no, you're not penalized double if it's parallel.

Comment: are you sure that CPU time is in microseconds? Adam Machanic seems to [think](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) that it is in milliseconds which also makes more sense with the values I am seeing.

Comment: You're totally right! I was thinking of the plan cache. Fixing the answer. Thanks!